# Logging in jms:message-driven-channel-adapter and jms:outbound-channel-adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I use jms:message-driven-channel-adapter and jms:outbound-channel-adapter in my project to get and put messages from/to IBM MQ . I need to get timestamps before and after each put and get. How could i achieve this. Please advise.

Please see my question updated below: 
We need time taken for each put and get operation. So what i believed is, if I could get the timestamp in the following way, I will be able to achieve what I wanted.

```
1)At jms:message-driven-channel-adapter: Note timestamp before and after each get -> derive time taken for each get 

2)At jms:outbound-channel-adapter: Note timestamp before and after each put -> derive time taken for each put
```

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It isn't clear what you want to have, because you always can get deal with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

But from other side Spring Integration maps a `jMSTimestamp` property of `JmsMessage` to the Message header `jms_timestamp` of incomming message in the `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>`.

Another point, that each Spring Integration Message has its own `timestamp` header.

So, if you switch on something like this:

```
<wire-tap channel="logger"/>

<logging-channel-adapter id="logger" log-full-message="true"/>
```

You always will see the `timestamp` fro each message in te logs, before it is sent to the channel.

**UPDATE**

OK. Thanks. Now it is more clear.

Well, for the outbound part (`put` in your case) I can say that your solution is laying with a custom `ChannelInterceptor` :

```
public class PutTimeInterceptor extends ChannelInterceptorAdapter {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        logger.info("preSend time [" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "] for: " + message);
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public void postSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent) {
        logger.info("postSend time [" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "] for: " + message);
    }

}
```

---

```
<channel id="putToJmsChannel">
   <interceptors>
       <bean class="com.my.proj.int.PutTimeInterceptor"/>
   </interceptors>
</channel>

<jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="putToJmsChannel"/>
```

Keep in mind that `ChannelInterceptor` isn't statefull, so you should `calculate` the `put` time manually for each message.

Another option is `<jms:request-handler-advice-chain>`, when you should implements the custom `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice`:

```
public class PutTimeRequestHandlerAdvice extends AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

    @Override
    protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) throws Exception {
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object result = callback.execute();
        logger.info("Put time: [" + System.currentTimeMillis() - before + "] for: " + message);
        return result;
    }
}
```

These are for the `put` only.

You can't derive the `execution time` for the `get` part, because it is a `MessageListener`, which is an `event-driven` component. When the message is in the queue you just receive it and that's all. There is no a hook to tie when the listener starts retrieve a message from the queue.

Comment: Artem, I have updated my question with the details. Please suggest. Will also look at your suggestion and respond back. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I am able to get the put time using your suggestion. And as you said, I understand that we could not get the "get time". But, is it possible to get the timestamp after  message-driven-channel-adapter picks up the message. Now I log the timestamp in the immediate method that is invoked after the message is picked up from MQ.

Comment: As I said: you can add `ChannelInterceptor` to the `channel` of your `message-driven-channel-adapter`. And `preSend` will be the best place to get the close time for message received from JMS.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I am able to log those timestamps now.